# Where I can find Button Override in Change Sets

Tags: button, salesforce, changeset

I want to move standard button override (Clone) on custom object through Outbound change Sets, but I'm unable to find this position in possible changes.

In which category Button Overrides are stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom buttons and links are listed in change sets under 'Button or Link'. To deploy the Page Layouts to which they are assigned, be sure to add it to the change set under 'Page Layouts'.

If you want to deploy a button overridden with a Visualforce page, you will need to deploy the whole object, the Visualforce page, its Apex Classes, and any components that are in the Visualforce page. In addition, once you have deployed the pages and classes, you will need to go into the new environment and give the appropriate profiles access to them, otherwise navigating to the page will give them an 'Insufficient Privileges' error.

If you want more finely-grained control over what specific metadata components you are deploying (and you don't simply want to do it manually in the target org) then you should consider using the ANT-based metadata migration tool that Salesforce provides. It has some more power and flexibility in terms of migrating sub-components of metadata. [Here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool) is a link with a little getting started video for that, and [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/index.htm) is the documentation.